# Sabre hotel price check - how long is the BookingKey valid for?

Tags: sabre

I'm using the REST API for Sabre GDS. When calling `POST /v3.0.0/hotel/pricecheck`, you get a `BookingKey` back to use in a call to `POST /v2.4.0/passenger/records?mode=create`. How long is that `BookingKey` value valid for, and is it configurable? I can't find that anywhere in the docs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabre support says the `BookingKey` is valid for 5 minutes.